# Flutter Local Notification - Problem with request Permission on Pixel 6

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, android-notifications, flutter-local-notification

I am trying to implement the flutter_local_notifications package. Somehow the permission request is not properly working on my Pixel 6 smartphone .

Only after I have executed the showNotification() function (see below) twice, a request permission for the push notification will be sent to my smartphone.

After the user has permitted the app to send push notifications, I will have to call the showNotification() function even a third time so that the push notifications will show up.

I find that very cumbersome, is there another way how to solve this problem? I would really appreciate any help on this matter!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest_all.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

    class ShowNotification{
   
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    Future<void> showNotification() async {
       const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_launcher');
    
       InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
    );

       await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
    );

       AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin androidImplementation = flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>();
       final bool granted = await androidImplementation.requestPermission();

       AndroidNotificationChannel channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
      '01',
      'Local notification',
      description: 'description',
      importance: Importance.max
    );

    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    DateTime scheduledNotification = DateTime.now().add(Duration(seconds: 5)); //TESTING
    final scheduledNotificationTime = scheduledNotification;

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(1,
        'HEADLINE',
        'TEXT',
        tz.TZDateTime.from(
          scheduledNotificationTime,
          tz.local,
        ),
        NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(channel.id, channel.name,
            channelDescription: channel.description,
            icon: '@drawable/ic_launcher',
            largeIcon: DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap('@drawable/ic_launcher'),
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.high,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    }
```